# Backtrace to mysql_close warnings in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm redoing a large portion of my website to use older mysql_* extensions because they execute faster. Yes I know people say its not a good idea to use older extensions, but I need to go for speed since this code is part of the back-end operations to my website and I want to serve as many people as possible.

I do have a small issue after converting things over. Sometimes when I try to close a database connection I get a PHP warning of:

```
PHP Warning:  mysql_close(): 33 is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in /path/to/script.php on line #
```

and the line refers to the code below:

```
function DBclose($c){
    if (isset($c) && !mysql_close($c)){
        error_log("DB handle is invalid/null. Called from ".debug_backtrace()[2]['function'].'->'.debug_backtrace()[1]['function']);
    }
}
```

This only happens sometimes.

What I want to do is change only this warning so that it includes the function that called it. Maybe to something more like:

```
PHP Warning:  mysql_close(): 33 is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in /path/to/script.php on line # called from parent function <function-name>
```

How do I fix this and still make it so that other function calls I make that begin with `@` will have no errors printed on screen?

Comment: if you want to go for speed ... go for `mysqli` and PHP 7, which is faster than PHP 5.x and mysql.

Comment: You may use [`debug_backtrace` function](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.debug-backtrace.php) to get parent function calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can change the message, however, you can  check if it's a resource using `is_resource()`